# sub setting a column between 2 dates

Tags: r, date, subset

I have a data frame named `nestle` and I have to find the volume of sales which has column header volume between two specified dates say 01-01-2010 and 01-01-2015. the dates were given as factors and I have converted them as date using `as.Date` syntax. I was trying to subset using-

```
 vol1 <- nestle(nestle$Volume >= "01-01-2010" & nestle$Volume <= "01-01-2015")
```

it is giving an error, saying

> could not find function "nestle"

I am new in R and trying to learn.

2nd part of my question is if i want to sub-set two coloumn in R which are the 1st column and 6th coloumn how should i do it?

I know how to do it if they are continuous i,e if they are from 3 to 6. I tried the same method but it showed an error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use brackets [ ], like `nestle[nestle$Volume >= "01-01-2010" & nestle$Volume <= "01-01-2015"]`

Comment: This would also work:  `vol1 <- subset(nestle, Volume >= "01-01-2010" & Volume <= "01-01-2015")`

Comment: I am sorry i totally forgot to use [ ].
however now the code is running successfully but the output is blank.
its showin 1843 entries but no columns or rows
i still have no clue why?

Comment: Please share ` dput(head(nestle)) ` and the code that you have used for the second part of your question.

Comment: my given data frame name was NESTLEIND.NS and i assign it to nestle
nestle <- NESTLEIND.NS
it has got 7 coloumns. The 1st one is date coloumn and the 6th one is column and i need to pull out these two columns.

i tried,

nestle01 <- NESTLEIND.NS[(c(1)),(c(6))] -> this code gives 27000

nestle02 <- NESTLEIND.NS[c(1) & c(6)] -> this gives out full table yet again.

Comment: @rar i don't know whats dput(head(nestle)).

Comment: ohk. I really got it.
i used-
nestle03 <- NESTLEIND.NS[c(1,6)]
this was simple, i was just making it complex.

however please tell me 
nestle01 <- NESTLEIND.NS[(c(1)),(c(6))]

nestle02 <- NESTLEIND.NS[c(1) & c(6)]

these two codes do?

Comment: Hey @PrashantKumar, you'll notice you got a lot of downvotes for this question. It is important that any code you provide is reproducible by others, and this means including a dataset (i.e. `nestle`). Also, questions should only target **one** specific issue, so avoid asking multiple questions. Check out here for some more tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am little bit sceptical that `Volume` column contains dates, usually it should be called something like "sales_date".

For date/time manipulation `lubridate` library is very convenient

```
# Simulation of data.frame w/10000 rows
set.seed(123)
library(lubridate)
NESTLEIND.NS <- data.frame(sales_date = as_date(sample(10000, replace = TRUE) + 10000), 
                           matrix((1:10000) * 5, ncol = 5), 
                           Volume = 10 * abs(rnorm(10000)))


nestle <- NESTLEIND.NS

# Date subsetting
nestle_date <- nestle[nestle$sales_date >= dmy("01-01-2010") & 
  nestle$sales_date <= dmy("01-01-2015"), ]

# check result
str(nestle_date)

# Column subsetting
nestle_column <- nestle[, c(1, 6)]

# Check result
str(nestle_column)
```